# LINQ2SQL No supported translation to SQL exists in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

We've been using LINQ2SQL on our mvc project for a while and its getting a bit long in the teeth.

One of the issues that we constantly face is the "No supported translation to SQL exists" when we try and do a query using something like.

LINQ2SQL partial class

```
public class User
{
   public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return (StartDate < DateTime.Now || StartDate == null) && (EndDate > DateTime.Now || EndDate == null);
            }
        }

   public DateTime? StartDate{get;set;}
   public DateTime? EndDate{get;set;}
}
```

and the query is something like

```
Datacontext.Users.Where(u => u.IsActive)
```

you get

> **The member 'User.IsActive' has no supported translation to SQL.**

We are considering moving to EF code first and I'm curious if this same problem exists, and if not how is EF working differently to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a user DTO class (that is not partial with the Linq2sql entity) there should be not problem to project into that class.

```
public class UserDTO
{
   public bool IsActive{get;set;}
   public DateTime? StartDate{get;set;}
   public DateTime? EndDate{get;set;}
} 

public IList<UserDTO> GetActiveUsers()
{
  using(var db = new DbContext())
  {
      var users = GetUsers(db);
      return users.Where(u => u.IsActive).ToList();
  }
}

private IQuerable<UserDTO> GetUsers(DbContext db)
{ 
    return (from u in db.Users
            select new UserDTO()
            {
               StartDate = u.StartDate,
               EndDate   = u.EndDate,
               IsActive  = (u.StartDate < DateTime.Now || u.StartDate == null) && (u.EndDate > DateTime.Now || u.EndDate == null)
            });
}
```

Comment: while that will solve the problem I'm more interested if this happens in EF